# php loop is breaking most of the time

Tags: php, foreach, httprequest, file-get-contents

i am using file_get_contents function to fetch a xml api and when i itrate this array using foreach loop it works fine but most of the time my php foreach loop is breaking not every time and different types of messages are shown. sometimes it gives "function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed" and sometimes it gives "Maximum time 30 second exceeded.

please help me. my code is

```
$data = $apiobj->search_slides($query,$per_page,$page);
$count = count($data);

$i=0;
foreach ($data as $key){
    $title = $key['TITLE'];
    $title2 = substr($title, 0, 35);

    echo '<td valign="top">
          <div id="slide_thum_des"><strong>Views :</strong> '.$info['VIEWS'].'<br />
          <a href="'.$key['DOWNLOADURL'].'">'.$title2.'....</a></div>
          </td>';
    $i++;

    if($i % 6 == 0) {
        echo '</tr><tr>';
    }
}
```

`$data = $apiobj->search_slides($query,$per_page,$page);` is the main function which gives array by parsing xml file in an another php code.

Comment: This has to do with the URLs you are querying. They may be unreachable, or blocking you.

Comment: but i am getting the xml output very clear and fine without any problem with that url. and i have said that this problem does not occur every time but it occurs 99% of the time.

Comment: It's still a HTTP problem. You'll need to find out why. For example, "HTTP request failed" *should* be followed by a status code that tells you more about what went wrong. Is it not?

Comment: `foreach ($data as $value)` would make more sense

Comment: @rajzana: That it doesn't occur all the time makes it _even more likely_ that there's an external factor at work. Not less.

Comment: Where's `file_get_contents` in your code? I don't see it.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal it's in the `search_slides` method. Which you should very much post here @rajzana.

Comment: No, he should not just dump selected functions. He should create a testcase, and he should have done this right at the start of his own debugging process.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's breaking in the loop?

Sounds like the initial http requests are failing (timing out by the sound of things).

You should try the http request and see it works.

Since you are using the file_get_contents function you should first suppress errors

```
$content = @file_get_content($url);
```

Then check if it worked

```
if($content == FALSE){ //error code goes here }
```

Comment: That's all true, but how would the OP do that? (Catch errors)

Comment: What you edited in doesn't help the OP find out what exactly went wrong.